# Spark Streaming Twitter Example: NoClassDefFoundError when using TwitterUtils.createStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to implement http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/big-data-mini-course/realtime-processing-with-spark-streaming.html or http://www.pwendell.com/2013/09/28/declarative-streams.html (although this uses an outdated version of Spark), but I keep ending up with:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/NetworkInputDStream

Here's some example code that causes the problem:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext("local[12]", "Twitter Downloader", Seconds(30))

//causes the error
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
```

Also, I'm using Scala and Eclipse

Thanks! (I can print more of the error or output if helpful)

Answer (score 1):

Solved--was using the .9 version of Spark-streaming-twitter (the .jar file) instead of 1.02